# Keeping the tab while navigating through accordion section links

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm working on a website implying php, javascript and jquery. It has 2 tabs and an accordion inside the second tab. When I click on a link from a section of the accordion, the website switches tab 2 with tab 1. I need to keep tab 2. I know that cookies are not the solution for this. 
Thank you very much for your reply!

Below is my written code:

```
    <!-- Inside the head tag of index.php -->
    $(function() {
  $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    heightStyle: "content"
  });
});

    $(function() {
       $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });


    <!-- Inside the <body> tag of index.php -->
    <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Products</a></li>
        </ul>
    <div class="tab" id="tabs-1">
      <h1>Content tab 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tab" id="tabs-2">
    <!-- The tab contains a table (one row, two columns). First column contains the 
         accordion, the second column shows the content behind the Products list item.
     -->
    <table>
       <tr>
         <td width="300">
          <div id="accordion">
         <h3>Products</h3>
      <div>
         <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php?pag=x1#tabs-2">Type 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?pag=x2#tabs-2">Type 2</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
          </div>
         </td>
         <td> 
    <?php

        if(isset($_GET['pag'])){
                switch($_GET['pag']){
                    case 'x1':include("pages/X1.php");break;
                    case 'x2':include("pages/X2.php");break;
                    default: include("pages/ui.php");
                }
            }else include("pages/ui.php");                      
    ?>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: If you are using the JQuery UI, have you read the tabs and accordion options? It is probably a problem with the triggering.

Comment: Your accordion is not working, have you done this according to the documentation? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ezgIJ

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I couldn't solve it, so I had to remove the tabs. Of course: everything was done considering the documentation...